# Dialog box units to screen coordinates

Tags: c++, windows, dialog, window, coordinates

Someone can explain me how to convert dialog box units to screen coordinates values ?
I saw that there is MapDialogRect function, but its converting RECT, i want to convert the x,y and cx,cy values to screen coordinate values and i dont really understand how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use MapDialogRect()? Do you want guidance on how to make up a RECT for it to work on?

Comment: Are you trying to read the DIALOGTEMPLATE in resources, and then convert??? or do you already have a created dialog?  If the latter, everything is already in screen units.

Comment: @ATT yes i need guidance how to convert the x,y,cx,cy values filled in DLGTEMPLATE from dialog box units to screen coordinates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have a window handle, then just use [the `MapDialogRect` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As others have noted, `MapDialogRect` takes a `RECT`, so if you don't have a `RECT`, you can create one.

```
RECT rc;
rc.left = x;
rc.top = y;
rc.right = x + cx;
rc.bottom = y + cy;
MapDialogRect(hdlg, &rc);
```

If your problem is that you don't have a dialog box handle in the first place, then the documentation for the `MapDialogRect` function tells you how to perform the calculations: Determine the the average character dimensions for the dialog box (which the documentation calls `baseunitX` and `baseunitY`) and then plug it into the formulas.

Note that this calculates the client rectangle of the dialog box. You still have to add non-client space. It's not clear what you're trying to do, so I don't know whether adding non-client space is appropriate or not.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when I call it from Windows Forms. (It returns FALSE.)

Comment: Windows Forms windows are not window manager dialogs.